# Is there a free Qt Jambi GUI Designer out there?

Tags: java, eclipse, qt-jambi

I am using Eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-08-2007/jw-08-qtjambi.html#resources there are two versions, a commercial one and one released under the LGPL. So, you get a free one for personal use, but commercial projects need to pay for the other version.

Answer (score 2):

Qt designer can be used to design GUI files with specific plugin installed by Jambi installers(use its own launcher, designer.bat/sh!), then they can be compiled to Jambi bytecode with command juic and that code will work in Jambi code like like code generated by uic works for Qt/cpp.

Eclipse integration is not open source, so last version it is supporting is Qt Jambi 4.5.